# If we Installed redgate tool "Schema Compare of Oracle" on a shared location

Tags: database, oracle, devops, redgate

If we Installed Redgate tool "Schema Compare of Oracle" on a shared location, Can we access "SCO.exe" Command line from a different Machine or Network? If Yes, Can we run multiple instances at the same time?
If we have more than on Developer than how many licenses we required?
Redgate tool License is Machine specifics or Login specifics?

Answer (score 1):

Redgate licensing is per-user. More information is available on [the documentation site](https://documentation.red-gate.com/ddfo/licensing).

If the use is as part of a server automated process, such as CI or automated release, each user contributing database changes will need a Deployment Suite for Oracle license. If the use of the sco.exe command line is not a server automated process (eg, running on a desktop), one Schema Compare for Oracle license is required for each distinct user. Per-user licensing allows a user to install the tools on as many machines as they need, provided the named user is using the tool.

Comment: If we Installed "Schema Compare of Oracle" on a shared location, Can we access "SCO.exe" Command line from a different Machine or Network? If Yes, Can we run multiple instances at the same time?

could you please help on that

Comment: I've never tried and it's the first time I've been asked this. I don't see why not. Why not try it and see? What is the reason for using it in this way?